# How to circumvent Rails 5 Devise user login authentication and instead redirect to page

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

My application has Devise deeply integrated and I wish to instead allow Apache to authenticate the user via SAML (to an IdP identity provider). Upon successful SAML login, Apache can then pass an environment variable that indicates the user_identifier.

Yet, I do not know how to tell Devise (or Warden) that the user is now logged in, and to not present the login page.

The routes.rb is similar to:

```
Authentication::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :user, {
    class_name: 'Authentication::Account',
    module: :devise,
    path_names: {
      sign_up: 'register',
      cancel: '',
    },
    controllers: {
      # ...
      sessions: 'authentication/sessions',
    }
  }

  devise_scope :user do
    root to: 'sessions#new'
    # ...
  end
```

I have made several attempts by adding a new() method to the SessionsController:

```
module Authentication
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new, :create], raise: false
    prepend_before_action(only: [:new, :create, :destroy]) { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true}

    def destroy
      # ...
    end

    # add new() method to override default Devise method
    def new
      user_identifier = ENV['uid']
      @user = Account.find_by_user_identifier(user_identifier)

      # super do
        store_location_for(:user, session[:origin_url])

        # dependent upon prepend_before_action, see rubydoc.info
        # sign_in(@user)  # didn't seem to sign user in, redirectors controller then calls destroy (above)

        bypass_sign_in(@user)

        # redirect_to session[:origin_url] and return
        # sign_in_and_redirect session[:origin_url] and return  # wrong?
        # sign_in_and_redirect @user  # wrong, loops through sign_in

        # resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user, :recall session[:origin_url])
        # resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)  # maybe?

        # sign_in_and_redirect(:user, resource)
        # redirect_to session[:origin_url] and return
      # end
    end
```

Most attempts result in sending the user to the login page, while others create an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* way to add other auth methods to Devise is via [OmniAuth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth) (Standardized Multi-Provider Authentication)

From the docs: *"OmniAuth is a library that standardizes multi-provider authentication for web applications. It was created to be powerful, flexible, and do as little as possible. Any developer can create strategies for OmniAuth that can authenticate users via disparate systems."*